# Linking directly to Facebook's stored og:image for a particular URL?

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-opengraph

It's pretty slick that Google lets you link to a website's favicon, simply like this:

http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.stackoverflow.com.  This is great because you can use this as the src of an image.

Anyone know of a similar way to link to the image defined in the og:image tag for a given web page -- a 3rd party URL, and not a Facebook-hosted "Page"?  This would be really handy, to do something like (and I'm making this up):

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/www.stackoverflow.com/og:image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done using open graph.

https://graph.facebook.com/[userId]/picture or 
https://graph.facebook.com/[pageId]/picture

For example:
**UserId**
https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture (Mark Zuckerberg's profile picture) or
**PageId**
https://graph.facebook.com/40796308305/picture (Coca Cola's profile picture) or
https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/picture

Comment: Thanks Neil.  So, you need to know the page ID for a given URL first?  Note that I mean 3rd party URLs, not Facebook-hosted Pages or profiles.

Comment: Yes you need the page ID or the actual page name. To get this navigate to the page in question and check what is in the url. e.g U2's facebook page is https://www.facebook.com/u2 so the link for their picture would be https://graph.facebook.com/u2/picture

Comment: I think we're talking about different things.  I want to know the og:image for www.u2.com, not facebook.com/u2.

Comment: Sorry @mungojerie, I understand what you are trying to do now. I don't think this is possible using the graph api but one option would be to scrape the web page for the og:image and display the results.